# Connect to Amazon ec2 through GUI from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vnc, vnc-server

How can I connect to Amazon ec2 through a GUI? I believe this requires setup of gui in the instance. I tried many links, right out of the first page, after googling, but I got stuck at the stage, where I have to use the VNC client to connect. Below is a sample client I am trying to use

[image]

Taking a sample amazon instance public dns

```
    ec2-<ip address>.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

How can I connect using VNC,or tightVNc after all the setup has been done?

**UPDATE 1**

The links I followed
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server)
[link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/634584/how-to-set-up-a-desktop-gui-with-an-amazon-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Typically the AWS linux instances are servers, with no UI installed. most instances don't have the RAM to run a UI. Also why pay for amazon CPU time just to run a UI?

If you do choose to install one or use a distro that has one, make sure you can get through the firewall. Create an SSH tunnel using your aws.pem file, I am assuming you can ssh in from the command line

`ssh -i aws.pem -f user@aws-server.com -L 5900:aws-server.com:5900 -N`

conect vnc to your localhost:5900, which will be the tunnel to AWS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to connect through ssh, terminal and I was able to install ubuntu-desktop. Plase check edit for the links I followed