# GUI tools to access AWS EC2 running Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm asking this here because google couldn't point me out in the proper direction. Are there any available tools for manipulating an EC2 instance via SSH using a GUI. I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu CLI commands (I actually crashed an instance by doing something over putty) so a GUI is my only option. What I actually want to do is to install a Glassfish web server on the instance. All necessary ports are forwarded (4848,8080,80).

Comment: This looks like a good guide to follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server

Comment: As well as https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/

Comment: Thank you @John this is exactly what I wanted