# Connecting to AWS EC2 instance through remote desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu `AWS EC2` instance running in the `AWS` cloud and in my Windows machine I am using PuTTy to connect to it. The problem with this way is that I just have one terminal CLI to access/edit all my code in `EC2` instance, which has many files and folders.

Is there a way where I can connect to `AWS EC2` to my Windows machine and access the code in my IDE? Something like Remote desktop connection?

Note: I can't test my code on my local machine because the services that I want to access have only whitelisted my `AWS EC2` IP.

Comment: *"The problem with this way is that I just have one terminal CLI to access/edit all my code in EC2 instance"*  Why would you not simply create multiple PuTTY sessions?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have been doing that. But don't you think its slow and tedious to do it this way?

Comment: Honestly, no.  That's exactly how I do it... although, for the past several weeks, I have been using [Ubuntu under WSL on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) and it's been a very pleasant surprise how well everything actually works -- my code is running locally with essentially no issues (other than utilities I've written that require certain low level access to things that simply aren't there). You might also find [AWS Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloud9-cloud-developer-environments/) interesting, if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 16):

Step 1: Open a ec2 Ubuntu terminal using a PuTTY. Refer for more detail how to connect your Linux instance from Windows using PuTTY https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Step 2: Run the following commands on PuTTY Ubuntu terminal step by step

> sudo apt update

Install xrdp to allow RDP connections:

> sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

> sudo apt install xrdp

Set a password for the ubuntu user:

> sudo passwd ubuntu

Step 3:

- Go to AWS console (EC2 Dashboard)
- Click on Instances(running)
- Select your running Ubuntu instance
- Go to Security
- Click on Security Groups
- Click on Edit inbound rules
- In type drop down select RDP
- It by default select port 3389
- In Source add 0.0.0.0/0 IP
- Click on Save rules

Step 4:

- Open Remote Desktop Connection on windows machine
- Enter Computer: Public IPv4 DNS of Ubuntu ec2 and add username:your_user_name
- click on connect will open up GUI version of Ubuntu (linux), It ask for password please enter the set password.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: at final step, after I input username + password and hit enter. The RDC window is force closed without any message. Do you know how to fix that? Thanks

Comment: Great answer: in all other tutorials I found, the part of enabling RDP in Security Groups was missing and therefore nothing worked

Comment: @VanHung just reboot your instance and your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VNC for that purpose 
https://medium.com/@Arafat./graphical-user-interface-using-vnc-with-amazon-ec2-instances-549d9c0969c5

Comment: Yes you need to install VNC client for windows and connect using it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server

Comment: Use this steps to setup the server side at the end download a VNC client for windows and connect to the server using the client.

Comment: I followed the medium guide. Everything done. But when connecting VNC viewer (on my local machine) to `localhost:5902`, I am getting error: `The connection was refused by the computer`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you opened port 5902 in security group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170094/discussion-between-skg-and-venkat-rao).

Comment: I haven't. I am looking for how to do that. Thanks.