# RDP Connection To Ubuntu Server from Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rdp, xrdp

In order to achieve a RDP connection to an Ubuntu server(AWS EC2) from another Ubuntu Server, I followed the steps of accepted answer in here: [How To Set Up GUI On Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server)

And I also tried these steps which are quite similar: https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2017/08/remote-desktop-on-an-ubuntu-ec2-instance/

But both of them does now answer my problem. When I connect to the server, the "login to xrdp" screen shows up and I wrote my username and password. Problem is that even it successfully connected to the server, it kicks me out of server after showing a yellow like screen for a second:https://i.hizliresim.com/JZBypJ.png

I could not figured out what is going on exactly. How can I solve this? Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the steps that is listed at below address.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely

The step that is not covered in the addresses which I gave in my questions is the step 3. Content of that step:

**Step 3 – Configure xRDP (From the address above)**

In this step, we modify two files to make sure xRDP uses Xfce4. First we need to create, or edit, our `.xsession` file in our home directory. We can either use nano or simply redirect an echo statement (easier):

```
echo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession
```

The second file we need to edit is the startup file for xRDP, so it will start Xfce4.

```
sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

The content should look like this (pay attention to the last line and ignore . /etc/X11/Xsession):

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

startxfce4
```

Hope that helps someone else with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To remote desktop your Ubuntu machine, Install xrdp and xfce.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xrdp && sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Configure xrdp:

```
Create .xsession in home directory.

echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession
```

Edit startup file for xrdp (notice that the last line is startxfce4)**[optional as it worked for me without doing this step]**

nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
  . /etc/default/locale
  export LANG LANGUAGE
fi

startxfce4
```

Restart xrdp service

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Create Ubuntu user password

```
sudo passwd ubuntuUser
```

**Log in:**

RDP to your remote machine and enter your Ubuntu credentials. You will be able to log in