# can't see terminal or anything other thing than aws ec2 vncserver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, gnome, vnc-viewer

I followed this guide to setup GUI for AWS EC2 instance: [HowTo: set a GUI in a Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BAoJ7JZHr0)

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop vnc4server gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal
```

Ubuntu version in AWS EC2

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

change: And use this ~/.vnc/xstartup file:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

but I don't see any terminal. I only see window. Can't open terminal

[image]

Comment: Q maybe can you send keystroke shortcut for terminal open "Ctrl+Alt+T" or command window "Alt+F2" ?

Comment: I agree with the OP here - the gnome-terminal does NOT work / appear when following these steps.  You can't launch it, even with the various key combinations.  Something is missing - I will do some digging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to setup GUI on a Ubuntu-based AWS EC2 instance, try following the steps mentioned here: [How to Install Graphical Desktop in AWS EC2 Instance ubuntu16.04 (Linux)](https://medium.com/@atinesh/setting-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server-part-i-8bbbd69f3f8e)

If you want to use an already available AWS EC2 AMI, try out any of the following:

1. [AWS EC2 AMI - Ubuntu GUI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07S8XH6V4)
2. [AWS EC2 AMI - Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS (HVM)](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01MEG2PVE)
3. [AWS EC2 AMI - Xubuntu GUI AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07MGHCWTB)

You can also explore answers to a similar question here: [Stackoverflow: How To Set Up GUI On Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657596/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server)

Comment: This answer is no longer useful - the main link is 404 not found.

Comment: @ib_so, Link is fixed now.